# Elastic search ORing and ANDing in query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use `ORing` and `ANDing` in my Elastic Search Query. I did parent -child mapping. I used query as:

```
{
  "from" : 0, "size" : 100,
    "query": {
      "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
                "query": {
                  "match_phrase": { 
                      "question_title": {
                        "query": 'searchKey',
                        "slop":  3
                    }
                  }
                }
            },
            {
                "query": {
                  "has_parent": {
                      "type": "question_data",
                      "query": {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "question_title": {
                              "query": 'searchKey',
                              "slop":  3
                          }
                        }
                      }
                  }
                }
            }
          ]
      }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: **OR** and **AND** on what?

Comment: can you share your schema and more detailed explanation for what you want to achieve

Comment: Suppose I have putted searchkey as **"baby crying"**. I want to get first records whose title contains "baby crying" string after that those records whose title contains "baby or cry" word , like that I want result. How can I make query for that?

Comment: Suppose I want to search for string as "baby cry". I just want to get sorted result as:  1 data which contains both the words. 2 after that data which contains any of one.